# Java Robot won't navigate dropdown menu with keypress

Tags: java

I'm using Java robot to script a boring task and everything is working fine except when I try to navigate a dropdown menu using

```
robot.keyPress(VK_DOWN);
robot.keyRelease(VK_DOWN);
```

VK_UP, VK_END and so on isn't working either. 
Simply nothing happens. Everything else works, moving mouse, clicking, typing in a textfield... I'm doing it in Safari.

Comment: Are you sure that the dropdownmenu has the focus of the browser?

Comment: Yeah it is. Thats the weird thing. In a textfield right next to it keyPress works without problem

Comment: when you use the awt robot sometimes the robot is too fast - try to wait a short time between **press** and **release**

Comment: Yeah that solved it! Thanks!

Comment: aha - i've worked with the robot some times and i had difficuties as well! Good luck furthermore!